# Show button based on magento2 version

Tags: magento2

I have added Reset Configuration button in system.xml but i want it only when magento version > 2.4. so is there any way to fullfill my requirnment ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you the full version (e.g: 2.4.4):

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface $productMetadata */
$productMetadata = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface');
$version = $productMetadata->getVersion();
```

Now add your logic based on the value.

***Note: Avoid using object manager, use DI***

[See here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/Version/Controller/Index/Index.php#L55)

Comment: is there any way to declaring magento version in system.xml & based on version. we can show the button ?

Comment: Add frontend renderer and check there

Comment: hy! thanks for the answer. but, can you please tell in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

In your system.xml try

```
<field id="generate_token_button" translate="label comment" type="button" sortOrder="27" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <frontend_model>MagePal\SmtpGoogleOauth\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\GenerateTokenButton</frontend_model>
    <depends>
        <field id="*/*/active">1</field>
    </depends>
</field>
```

In class MagePal\SmtpGoogleOauth\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\GenerateTokenButton.php

```
namespace MagePal\SmtpGoogleOauth\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
.....

class GenerateTokenButton extends Field
{
    ...

    protected function _decorateRowHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element, $html)
    {
      return $this->isGreaterThan24() ? parent::_decorateRowHtml() : '';
    }

    /** return bool **/
    public function isGreaterThan24()
    {
       return version_compare($this->productMetadata->getVersion(), '2.4.0', '>=');
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer